# How to replace a char at the cursor in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs

I want to create a minor mode that helps to input thai tone character.
This is what I wrote:

```
(defvar thai-input-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "2" (lambda () (interactive)
              (replace-string "o" "ô")
              ))
    map)
  "Keymap used by `thai-input-mode'.")
(easy-mmode-define-minor-mode thai-input-mode
                              "Input mode for Thai"
                              nil  " TH" thai-input-mode-map)
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-t" 'thai-input-mode)
```

Of course I must implement more details, but I'm already have problems.
First of all the `replace-string` function doesn't work even if there is `o` in a buffer.
Secondly I couldn't figure out how to replace only a character that is at the cursor.

How can I write to implement that kind of function?

### Edit

By following Gilles's advice I wrote like this:

```
(defvar thai-tone-conversion-list
    '(("o" . "ô") ("u" . "û")))
(defun thai-add-tone ()
  (interactive "*")
  (when (let ((case-fold-search t))
          (looking-back "[ou]"))
    (replace-match (assoc (match-string 0) (thai-tone-conversion-list)))))
(defvar thai-input-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "2" 'thai-add-tone)
    map)
  "Keymap used by `thai-input-mode'.")
(easy-mmode-define-minor-mode thai-input-mode
                              "Input mode for Thai"
                              nil  " TH" thai-input-mode-map)
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-t" 'thai-input-mode)
```

But I get `assoc: Symbol's function definition is void: thai-tone-conversion-list` error, when I put `2` in `thai-input-mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(replace-string "o" "ô")` replaces the next occurrence of `o` after the cursor¹, except in transient mark mode with an active mark in which case it replaces the first occurrence in the marked region.

This works to replace the character after the cursor, but of course if that isn't an `o` then it could replace a character further. You could use the START and END arguments to `replace-string` to limit the extent of the replacement, but this won't scale. Use [`char-after`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Near-Point.html#index-char_002dafter-2816) to retrieve the character after the cursor, and [`char-before`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Near-Point.html#index-char_002dbefore-2817) to retrieve the character before the cursor. This function looks like it's meant to be used after typing an `o`, so I think `char-before` is what you're looking for.

```
(require 'cl)
(defun thai-add-tone ()
  (interactive "*")
  (case (char-before)
   ((?o)
    (delete-backward-char 1)
    (insert "ô"))
   ((?u)
    (delete-backward-char 1)
    (insert "û"))))
```

An alternative approach is to make a test (or a series of tests) with [`looking-at`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html#index-looking_002dat-3352) (for text starting at the cursor) or [`looking-back`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html#index-looking_002dback-3353) (for text ending at the cursor). You can then call [`replace-match`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Match.html#index-replace_002dmatch-3364) to replace the text; this allows some automation, for example Emacs can take care of replacing lowercase by lowercase and uppercase by uppercase.

```
(defvar thai-tone-conversion-list
    '(("o" . "ô") ("u" . "û")))
(defun thai-add-tone ()
  (interactive "*")
  (when (let ((case-fold-search t))
          (looking-back "[ou]"))
    (replace-match (cdr (assoc (match-string 0) thai-tone-conversion-list)))))
```

Note that Emacs already has some support for Thai, it may be easier to build upon it than to reinvent the wheel. You can select one of two Thai input methods with `set-input-method` (`C-x RET C-\`). There doesn't appear to be any documentation in English beyond the [source code](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/language/thai.el).

¹  <sub>In Emacs terminology, the “cursor” as in the position at which edits are made is called *point*. The word *cursor* is reserved for the visual artifact on the screen that marks the position of the point.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Gilles! I followed your advice, but there is a error I can't fix. I added the code in my question. Could you help me?

Comment: And the `lisp/language/thai.el` seems to be a input method thai character. I want to input thai pronunciation alphabet. The two are different.

Comment: @Tetsu My mistake, remove the parentheses around `thai-tone-conversion-list`.

Comment: I still get a error `progn: Wrong type argument: stringp, ("o" . "ô")`. I also tried the first method, with the function `thai-add-tone` I get error like this: `cond: Wrong number of arguments: #[(n &optional killflag) "¨`.

Comment: @Tetsu See my edit. I tested the code this time.

Comment: So I had to add `cdr` there, thank you very much!